# How to change text field on select drop down box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<p>
    <%= f.label :website_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :website_name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :website_type %><br />
    <%= f.select :website_type, Media::ALL_MEDIA_TYPES, :include_blank => true %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :media_link %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :media_link %>
</p>
```

Here I want to set the pattern in "media_link" on selecting option in drop down. If I choose facebook in drop down then media_link should accept only facebook link pattern. for example http://www.facebook.com/stevemaddon. Option in drop down can be blogs or twitter.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you trying to set the text in the text field, or are you trying to validate the text in the text field? The former would be done in Javascript. The latter would best be done with a custom validation in the model. Controller logic would suffice if you don't have a model.

Comment: I am trying to validate text. I have model, so in this I guess I need to write a method??

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna be real with you, I'm not sure if you're trying to do this dynamically or what, but take this and tell me how this does/doesn't work for you.

```
input = [:media_link]
if params[:website_type] == #Facebook website_type id
  if !input["facebook.com/"] #Or whatever regexp you want to use
    redirect_to :back, flash[:message] => "Must be a Facebook URL"
  end
end
if params[:website_type] == #Twitter website_type id
  if !input[/^http:\/\/twitter\.com\/(?:#!\/)?(\w+)\/status(es)?\/(\d+)$/] 
    redirect_to :back, flash[:message] => "Must be a Twitter URL"
  end
end
```

Comment: I am going to add all these credentials on new page. so case if user selects twitter from drop down then text field media_link should only take this pattern " /^http:\/\/twitter\.com\/(?:#!\/)?(\w+)\/status(es)?\/(\d+)$/" or other like facebook

Comment: Should this be a dynamic validation? Like with JavaScript where it only allows one to type in that pattern? You keep using the word "accepts" which makes me think so

Comment: **validates_format_of :social_media_handle, :with => /^http:\/\/twitter\.com\/(?:#!\/)?(\w+)\/status(es)?\/(\d+)$/, :unless => :social_media**

def social_media

   self.social_media_handle.match(/twitter/)
end . For above question I am using this, right now this only for twitter how I would do for other options like facebook and any blogs??

Comment: Many may disagree with me, but I would do it in the controller, like I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
validate :social_media_format

MEDIA_LINK_FORMATS = {
  :twitter => /^http:\/\/twitter\.com\/(?:#!\/)?(\w+)\/status(es)?\/(\d+)$/,
  :facebook => /.../
}

def social_media_format
  errors.add(:media_link, "does not match #{website_type}") unless media_link =~ MEDIA_LINK_FORMATS[website_type.to_sym]
end
```